# Python's isdigit() method returns False for negative numbers

Tags: python, integer

I have a text files that I read to a list. This list contains integers and strings.

For example, my list could look like this:

```
["name", "test", "1", "3", "-3", "name" ...]
```

Now, I want to convert all numbers into integers using the `.isdigit()` method or the `isinstance()` function.
for example:

```
for i in range len(mylist):
    if mylist[i].isdigit():
        mylist[i] =  int(mylist[i])
```

The problem is that `"-3".isdigit()` for example would return `False`. Any tips for a simple solution to circumvent the problem and convert negative-digit-strings into negative integers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The method tests for *digits* only, and `-` is not a digit. You need to test with `int()` and catch the `ValueError` exception instead if you wanted to detect integers:

```
for i, value in enumerate(mylist):
    try:
        mylist[i] = int(value)
    except ValueError:
        pass  # not an integer
```

In other words, there is *no need* to test explicitly; just convert and catch the exception. Ask forgiveness rather than ask for permission.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Then vote for Ned's answer! He just crossed that line! I am a few days away still.

Comment: I'd love to hear what is not helpful or wrong about my answer, to deserve a downvote. That way I can improve my answer!

Comment: I think this answer and Ned's answer are equivalent, but somehow op seems to be not particularly fond of this while he shows gratitude for ned's..

Comment: `+1` two days to be exact! `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Try it, and catch the exception if it fails:

```
try:
    return int(obj)
except ValueError:
    ...
```

Python takes the view of *it's easier to ask for forgiveness than permission*. Looking before you leap is often slower, harder to read, and can often introduce race conditions (not in this instance, but in general).

Also, modifying a list in-place like that is a bad idea, as accessing by index in Python is slow. Instead, consider using a [list comprehension](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) like this:

```
def intify(obj):
    try:
        return int(obj)
    except ValueError:
        return obj

mylist_with_ints = [intify(obj) for obj in mylist]
```

This makes a new list with the modified values and is more readable and efficient.

As a note, as we are just applying a function to every item of a list, `map()` would also work well here:

```
mylist_with_ints = map(intify, mylist)
```

Note that if you need a list instead of an iterable in 3.x, you will want to wrap the map call in `list()`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to convert to integers is to try the conversion and be prepared for it to fail:

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    try:
        mylist[i] = int(mylist[i])
    except ValueError:
        pass
```