# Why doesn't my random number generator give the correct message when the user inputs a negative number in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

max_number = input("Please type in the highest number for the range: ")

if max_number.isdigit():
    max_number = int(max_number)
    if max_number <= 0:
        print("Please type a number larger than 0")
        quit ()
else:
    print('Please type a number')
    quit()

random_number = random.randint( 0 , max_number )

print(random_number)
```

im making a random number generator but when i input a number like -9 it still gives me Please type a number and not Please type a number larger than 0

I expected the first print result but got the second one

Comment: Duplicate of [Python's isdigit() method returns False for negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720176/pythons-isdigit-method-returns-false-for-negative-numbers)

Comment: isdigit() checks if the string you passed is all digits. Negative sign is not considered a digit.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `.isdigit()` logic [found here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit).

```py
"9".isdigit() -> True
"-9".isdigit() -> False
```

You'll need to modify the code to use either regex, or strip away the `-` if it's the first character of the input.

Here's a small integer numbers cheatsheet as well: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s01.html.